# A Directed Preorder from a Local Base

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Prove that if $\mathscr{A}$ is a local base at point $p \in (X, \mathscr{T})$, then $\supset$ (the superset relation) is *directed* on $\mathscr{A}$.

---

Here are the definitions I am given for this problem

Call a preorder $R$ on a set $I$ *directed* if for all $x,y \in I$, there exists $z \in I$ such that $xRz$ and $yRz$.

If $\trianglelefteq$ is a directed preorder on $I$ and $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ is an $I-$sequence of points in $(X, \mathscr{T})$, say that  $\lim_{i \in I} x_i=y$ if for every open $y \in U,$ there exists $k\in I$ such that $(k \trianglelefteq n \Rightarrow x_n \in U)$.

Given $p \in X, \mathscr{A}$ is a *local base* at $p$ if  $\mathscr{A} \subset \mathscr{T}$ and $\left( \forall A \in \mathscr{A}, p \in A\right)$, and $\left(\forall U \in \mathscr{T} (p \in U \Rightarrow \exists A \in \mathscr{A} : p \in A \subset U) \right)$.

---

Based on what I have read so far, if a set is directed, then every two elements in $I$ have an upper bound, but not necessarily a least upper bound.  We want to show that the preorder $\supset$ has the property that $x \supset z$ and $y \supset z$ for all $x,y \in I$.

I am very confused as to how we proceed in solving this problem. How does one show this result? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need the definition of limit along a directed set: it’s not relevant here. This definition of *local base* at a point is standard; you’ll want to remember it. It just says that $\mathscr{A}$ is a local base at $p$ if $\mathscr{A}$ is a collection of open nbhds of $p$ such that every open nbhd of $p$ is a superset of some member of $\mathscr{A}$. For instance, in $\Bbb R$ the set of intervals of the form $\left(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ is a local base at $x$.

Now, back to the actual problem. You’re asked to show that if $\mathscr{A}$ is a local base at some point $p\in X$, then $\langle\mathscr{A},\supseteq\rangle$ is a directed set. As you say, this requires showing that if $A,B\in\mathscr{A}$, then $A$ and $B$ have an upper bound in $\mathscr{A}$ relative to the order $\supseteq$. Translate that into simpler terms: you want to show that there is a $C\in\mathscr{A}$ such that $A\supseteq C$ and $B\supseteq C$.

If we knew that $A\cap B$ was a member of $\mathscr{A}$, we could use it; unfortunately, it need not be a member of $\mathscr{A}$. However, $A\cap B$ *is* guaranteed to be an open nbhd of $p$, and therefore it contains ... ?

Comment: you is a genius sir (+1) Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy: You’re welcome!

Comment: Since $A \cap B $ is an open neighborhood of $p$, then would it contain the set $C \in \mathscr{A}$ by definition of local base?

Comment: @Jamil: I wouldn’t say *the* set $C$, but yes, it would have to contain *some* member of $\mathscr{A}$, simply because $\mathscr{A}$ is a local base at $p$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thank you very much, again, for your explanations.

Comment: @Jamil: You’re very welcome.